# Host angularjs.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Tags: macos, dns, hosts, hosts-file, known-hosts

My MacBook Pro OSX 10.9.4 has network problems now, and I cannot figure it out what is causing the problem.

Today I am not able to access [angularjs.org](https://angularjs.org) with any browser, but I can access other websites.

Chrome Developer Tools console tells me this:

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

When I run: `$ host angularjs.org` the output is `Host angularjs.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

When I run: `$ host superuser.com` the output is `superuser.com has address 198.252.206.16`

My hosts file is:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

**How can I solve this or get more info about the problem?**

Answer (score 0):

The NXDOMAIN reply means that the resolver you are talking to claims that this domain does not exist. Find out what resolver you are using and start troubleshooting there.